# How to print the alphabets in alternate reverse and alphabetical order?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I am new to programming. I am presently learning python.
I have a list in the alphabetical order.

Now I want to convert this list in such a way that the new list L2 looks somewhat like

`L2= A,Z,B,Y,C,X,D,W,E,V,F,U,G.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `string.ascii_uppercase` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase)):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

l = sum(map(list, zip(ascii_uppercase, ascii_uppercase[::-1])), [])

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'Z', 'B', 'Y', 'C', 'X', 'D', 'W', 'E', 'V', 'F', 'U', 'G', 'T', 'H', 'S', 'I', 'R', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'P', 'L', 'O', 'M', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'O', 'L', 'P', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'R', 'I', 'S', 'H', 'T', 'G', 'U', 'F', 'V', 'E', 'W', 'D', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'B', 'Z', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
>>> ','.join(chain(*zip(a, reversed(a))))
'A,Z,B,Y,C,X,D,W,E,V,F,U,G,T,H,S,I,R,J,Q,K,P,L,O,M,N,N,M,O,L,P,K,Q,J,R,I,S,H,T,G,U,F,V,E,W,D,X,C,Y,B,Z,A'
>>>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.